# Automatically keep current sshd_config file when upgrading openssh-server

Tags: apt, upgrade, openssh

When upgrading openssh-server, the installation pops up a dialog menu asking the user what they want to do with the sshd_config file.  I need to keep the current sshd_config file because it conforms to corporate security rules.  Is there a way to bypass the dialog menu while keeping the current config file?  I tried this:

`apt-get install -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" --force-yes -y openssh-server`

But it errored out with "--force-yes is deprecated, use one of the options starting with --allow instead."  So far I haven't found an "--allow" option that will keep the current sshd_config file without user input.  Anyone know know how to do this?

Comment: The [current Debian documentation](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.package-meta-information.html#sidebar.questions-conffiles) on this topic, which suggests the use of `apt`, and the omission of the troublesome `--force-yes`

Comment: Thank you, but adding Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" to the apt-get install cmd still does not prevent the dialog option menu from popping up.

Answer (score 1):

For this specific package that use UCF, you have to use UCF_FORCE_CONFFOLD=1

```
UCF_FORCE_CONFFOLD=1 apt-get install -y openssh-server
```